# Yii2 minifying asset bundles throws error on external library

Tags: yii2, assets, minify

I've setup my asset bundles and am trying to run the asset console command to minify my JS and CSS files and it throws an error on one of my bundles that uses an external library

```
 'file_get_contents(/httpdocs/site-name/frontend-test/assets/e4efadb7/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&amp;libraries=&amp;language=): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'
```

the Asset file in question is as follows:

```
public $sourcePath = '@frontend/assets/web';
public $css = [
    //'css/site.css',
];
public $js = [
    'js/google_map.js',
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&amp;libraries=&amp;language='
];
public $depends = [
    'frontend\assets\AppAsset',
];
```

If I remove the external library, it all works fine but then, as you would expect, the page doesn't load properly.

Is there a method to get the asset console command to understand absolute urls?  or should I just include this with a call to registerJSFile ?

UPDATE:

I tried creating a blank js file locally so that the compression runs through correctly and then changing the mapping in the config files as follows:-

```
'assetManager' => [
        'assetMap' => [
            'js/googleapis.js' => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&amp;libraries=&amp;language='
        ],
   ...
 ]
```

But of course it won't load as it's all compressed and not trying to load js/googleapis.js!

I've had to resort to loading using registerJsFile but this seems messy.  I was hoping Asset bundles would keep payloads together!  Oh Well ...

Comment: you want to minify "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&amp;libraries=&amp;language="    file too

Comment: No but I would prefer to keep it in my asset bundle.  wondering if I can map it.